# Comparing results for spectrum generating in matlab using STFT and Filterbank approach

Tags: matlab, frequency-spectrum, stft, filter-bank

To analyse data in the frequency domain I often use functions like `stft()` in Matlab. Inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-q9gwYZZ1o) and [this article](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/high-resolution-spectral-analysis-in-matlab.html) I have compared the results of spectrums generated by `stft()` and a `Filterbank` approach. I am quite pleased with the result of the 2nd method. However I wonder if there are other ways or methods to achieve this result? For instance I wonder if `dsp.Channelizer` could be used for this?

Also I have observed vertical lines in the Filterbank-result that seem to coincide with the number of overlap samples. Is there a way to reduce those vertical lines? Also the background noise seems to be higher than in the `stft`-case. Is there a way to improve this with the filterbank approach?

[image: Spectra vs Time plot for a voice recording generated with stft-function and with a filterbank approach]

Here is the Matlab-code to generate both plots (in both cases 247 timesteps and a frequency resolution of 24Hz are used):

```
load mtlb
t=0:1/Fs:((length(mtlb)-1)*(1/Fs));

M = round(Fs/24); % Window-Length in Sample-Nrs
L = round(M*0.95); % How much samples overlap
lk = 0.8; % leakage
g = kaiser(M,40*(1-lk)); % build the window to multiply the signal with

[S1,F,T] =     stft(mtlb/sum(g)*sqrt(2),Fs,"Window",g,"OverlapLength",L,"FFTLength",M,'FrequencyRange','onesided'    );

FrameSize = M;
NumFreqBins = M;
filterBankEstimator = dsp.SpectrumEstimator(... % build the Filterbank
    'Method','Filter bank',...
    'AveragingMethod','Exponential', ...
    'ForgettingFactor',0.4, ...
    'SampleRate',Fs,...
    'FrequencyRange','onesided',...
    'PowerUnits','dBW');

buff    = dsp.AsyncBuffer; % buffer input-timedata for the Filterbank
timesteps=(M-L); % Time steps for Filterbank calculations
count=1;
T2=[];
S2=[];
F2=0:Fs/M:floor(Fs/2);
for i = 1:timesteps:(length(mtlb)-FrameSize)
    x=mtlb(i:i+FrameSize-1);
    write(buff,x);      % Buffer data
    if buff.NumUnreadSamples >= NumFreqBins
        xbuff = read(buff,NumFreqBins);
        S2(:,count) = filterBankEstimator(xbuff);
        T2(end+1)=t(i);
        count=count+1;
    end
end

oGrenz=max([mag2db(abs(S1(:)).^2/2e-5); mag2db(db2pow(S2(:))/2e-5)]);
delta=80;

subplot(1,2,1)
pcolor(T,F,mag2db(abs(S1).^2/2e-5));
shading flat
axis tight
colorbar
caxis([oGrenz-delta oGrenz])
title("STFT")
xlabel("Time in s")
ylabel("Frequency in Hz")

subplot(1,2,2)
pcolor(T2,F2,mag2db(db2pow(S2)/2e-5));
shading flat
axis tight
colorbar
caxis([oGrenz-delta oGrenz])
title("Filterbank")
xlabel("Time in s")
ylabel("Frequency in Hz")
```

**Edit**

According to @Hilmar's suggesstion I want so specify my question:

- (+) I like the frequency-peaks being sharper with the filterbank method
- (-) However, I would like to get rid of the vertical lines with the filterbank method. I assume I'm doing something suboptimal with the buffer.
- (-) As can be seen with the below plot with the increased color limits, the background noise seems to be higher with the filterbank method (light blue vs dark blue). Is there a way to achieve similar levels?

[image: STFT vs Filterbank Spectra-Time-Plot]

Comment: In order to "improve" things, you need to clearly state the criteria by which you measure improvement. Spectral analysis typically requires a complex set of trade offs and without knowing what's important to you and what isn't, it's difficult to give any guidance.

Comment: @Hilmar: Thank you for the hint! I edited the question and tried to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

With the following changes

```
...



t=1/(100*Fs)*[0:1:length(mtlb)-1];

M = round(Fs/24); % Window-Length in Sample-Nrs
L = round(M*0.95); % How much samples overlap
lk = 0.8; % leakage
g = kaiser(M,40*(1-lk)); % build the window to multiply the signal with

[S1,F,T] =     stft(mtlb/sum(g)*sqrt(2),10*Fs,"Window",g,"OverlapLength",L,"FFTLength",M,'FrequencyRange','onesided'    );

FrameSize = M;
NumFreqBins = M;
filterBankEstimator = dsp.SpectrumEstimator(... % build the Filterbank
    'Method','Welch',... % 'Filter bank',...
    'FFTLength',128*2^4,...
    'AveragingMethod','Exponential', ...
    'ForgettingFactor',.01, ...
    'SampleRate',10*Fs,...
    'FrequencyRange','onesided',...
    'PowerUnits','dBW');
...
```

I have stopped when the *'vertical lines'* gone.

Note that changing `Method` from `Filter bank` to `Exponential` .

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and thank you for your efforts! Actually I would like to use the Filterbank method as it provides sharper frequency-peaks. So changing to Welchs method is something I like to avoid. In the video linked above the benefits of the Filterbank method compared to Welch are explained.
However I achieve sharper frequency-peaks with the filterbank method, but I also get those weird vertical lines. I assume I do something wrong with the buffer and the overlapping. Or maybe I should do averaging of the spectra afterwards?